# Formatting the text in an e-mail

Tags: php, email

Sorry, still a novice but getting better.  I'm building a website and because I'm not that good I'm providing a page where club members can report problems and give me enough information to look into it.  I have written the PHP code to send me an e-mail.  If I echo the $message it prints fine on the screen but in an e-mail it's just one long sentence with the HTML tags in it.  I searched for a solution and tried the ""Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8"" but that did nothing.  I know I'll be embarrassed when I get the answer but I am stuck.  Thanks in advance.

```
<?php  
//  Convert form data to srting data

    $first_name=$_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name=$_POST['last_name'];
    $e_mail=$_POST['e_mail'];
    $browser=$_POST['browser'];
    $browser_version=$_POST['browser_version'];
    $os=$_POST['os'];
    $os_ver=$_POST['os_ver'];
    $device=$_POST['device'];
    $make=$_POST['make'];
    $issue=$_POST['issue'];

//  Use string data to create and send e-mail

    $to = '*******@*****.com';  //  will need to be converted to webmaster@stjoesclub.com
    $subject = 'Problem with St. Joseph Web Site';
    $message = $first_name . " " . $last_name . " is reporting a problem with the web site. <br><br>" .
               "E-mail address:  " . $e_mail . "<br><br>" .
               "Browser:  " . $browser . "<br>" .
               "Browser Version:  " . $browser_version . "<br><br>" .
               "Operating System:  " . $os . "<br>" .
               "Operating System Version:  " . $os_ver . "<br><br>" .
               "Device:       " . $device . "<br>" .
               "Device Make:   " . $make . "<br><br>" .
               $issue;


//  Send e-mail to webmaster

    mail($to, $subject, $message, 'From: ' . $e_mail, "Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8");

?>
```

Comment: Don't send yourself errors via email, log them to files!

Comment: Your headers should contain  `"Content-Type: text/html;"`.

Comment: E-mail was invented many years before the WWW. It will never default to HTML and specifying `text/plain` is not going to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `Content-Type` as `text/html` as below

```
$eol="\r\n";

# Common Headers
$headers = "Message-ID: <".time()."-".$e_mail.">".$eol;
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP v".phpversion().$eol;                      
// These two to help avoid spam-filters

# Boundry for marking the split & Multitype Headers
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0'.$eol;
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1".$eol.$eol;

mail($to, $subject, $message, 'From: ' . $e_mail, $headers);
```

Comment: I have to be honest, this code is SOOOO far about my pay grade!  I tried it but unfortunately it didn't work.  The next to last line sends a blank mail that says it's from my web hosting company.  The last line sends an e-mail exactly like the one I had before.  (Yes, I did comment out the mail code I had, so that's not what's happening.  But I thank you for the effort, I have saved the code in my notes and when I have time I'll read up on it and try to understand what was going on.

Comment: I am using second last line in my code, I forgot to remove before add here :)

Answer (score 0):

`Content-Type` should be set to `text/html` as said by @Ben Fortune

Comment: I thought that would work but it didn't.  Unless my syntax is wrong.  I used "Content-type: text/html" but I still get the HTML tags for <br>.  I use Outlook 2007 and I am set to accept html e-mail.  Thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

Eureka!  Thanks to the help from Harish Singh I was able to solve my own issue.  Looking at his code one problem I found was that the string $mailHtml was undefined which was the reason for a blank e-mail.

But learning from his code I figured out the $eol stood for End Of Line.  By using that instead of the 
 the e-mail formats correctly when it comes in via the e-mail.

Unfortunately it doesn't work if I echo the $message on the screen after submission but fortunately I saved the old code so I can print it properly.  I know that's not effective code but for a rookie hack it works.

Thanks again for the help.

Comment: I am using $mailHtml as a complete html in my own code, I forgot to remove before add here :)